# Open-source library suggestion: Semantic Role Labeling

Tags: llm, parsing

Can I be referred to a SOTA model/script/pipeline with a commercially open-source license for  Semantic Role Labeling or semantic parsing? I prefer it to be based on the most recent LLM to achieve high accuracy.

Comment: If you want an LLM-based solution, you can just request SRL analysis from the LLM directly, e.g. [this](https://unimatrixz.com/topics/ai-text/nlp-tasks/advanced-nlp-tasks/semantic-role-labeling/)